# When to use static attributes?

Tags: java, reference, static, attributes

I recently had to write a program for my University programming class. After some hours i 
finally finished it and everything worked just fine(so i thought).The program should actually contain two classes one of them (the main) BookTest should create an object and then call all methods from the Book class.The problem is that the attributes (id,title,author,dateOfPublication) should not be static.Is there a way to make it work without the attributes being static. This are the two classes where i get the errors because i do not have the attributes static.Everywhere where my attributes appear in methods it gives me the error can not make static reference to the non static method `methodname()` from the type Book.Every help is very much appreciated!

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;

public class Book
{
private int id;
private String title;
private String author;
private Date dateOfPublication;

public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy";

//--- constructors ---
public Book(int ID,String TITLE,String AUTHOR,Date DATEOFPUBLICATION){
    setId(ID);
    setTitle(TITLE);
    setAuthor(AUTHOR);
    setDateOfPublication(DATEOFPUBLICATION);
    }
   public Book() {
}

   /** Returns the age of the book in days since publication */
    public int age(){
    Date date = new Date();
    long difference = date.getTime() - Book.getDateOfPublication().getTime();
    long differenceDays = difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    return (int) differenceDays; //this is to avoid compiler errors, replace it!
    }
   /** Returns a String representation of the book */
   public String toString(){
   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
   String dateAsString = simpleDateFormat.format((Book.getDateOfPublication()));
   String Documentation;
   Documentation = String.valueOf(Book.getId())+", " + Book.getTitle()+", " + Book.getAuthor()+",     "     + dateAsString;     
   return Documentation; //this is to avoid compiler errors, replace it!
}
/** Reads all book data from user input */
public void input(){
    Scanner scn = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println( "Please enter id: " );
    Book.setId(scn.nextInt());
    scn.nextLine();
    System.out.println( "Please enter title: " );
    Book.setTitle((scn.nextLine()));
    System.out.println( "Please enter author: " );
    Book.setAuthor(scn.nextLine());
    System.out.println( "Please enter Date of Publication: " );
    String string_dateOfPublication  = scn.nextLine();
    Book.setDateOfPublication(stringToDate(string_dateOfPublication));
    scn.close();
    }
    //--- Get-/Set-methods ---


   public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
//--- helper methods -- DO NOT CHANGE ------------------------------------
/** Converts the Date object d into a String object */
public static String dateToString( Date d )
{
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat( DATE_FORMAT );
    return fmt.format( d );
}

/** Converts the String object s into a Date object */
public static Date stringToDate( String s ) 
{
    Date r = null;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat( DATE_FORMAT );
        r = fmt.parse( s );
    } catch ( ParseException e ){
        System.err.println( e );
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return r;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}
public Date getDateOfPublication() {
    return dateOfPublication;
}
public void setDateOfPublication(Date dateOfPublication) {
    this.dateOfPublication = dateOfPublication;
}
}



public class BookTest{

public static void main (String []args){

    Book Bookobj = new Book();
    Bookobj.input();
    System.out.println(Book.age()+" Tage alt.");
    System.out.println(Bookobj.toString());

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [static members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). A (simplified) way to think of it is that a non-static member (field, method) is one which is provided by an *instance*, while a static member is one which is provided by a *class*.

In your `Book` class case, each book has a name, author etc. which are properties belonging to a specific book (instance). Then it makes sense that they should be non-static. The same goes for their getter and setter methods and all other instance specific methods.

The methods converting strings and dates are not specific to an instance. The class `Book` provides them. As such, they are called by

```
Book.stringToDate(...);
```

which makes sense, because converting is not a book-specific feature \ property.

In your `main`, you create an instance of `Book`:

```
Book bookObj = new Book(); // instance names should start with a lowercase
```

and then you want the user to enter data for *this specific book*, so you need to call

```
bookObj.input(); // Not Book.input()
```

and the same for the operations afterwards.

Inside the class definition (let's look at `input`), you are calling the non-static setter methods as if they are static:

```
Book.setId(...);
```

In fact, you want to set the ID for *this specific instance*. So what you need to write is

```
this.setId(...);
```

where the keyword `this` gives a reference to the current instance of the class you are in (`Book` in this case). Note that you can remove the keyword `this` and write

```
setId(...);
```

as the invoker of the method is automatically implied.

Comment: With your answer i was able to figure it out.Now i understand why my attributes should not be static and how to change the other code so that it works.Thanks a million !

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your getters and setters by the class name, which is how you would call a static method. Because you are calling them by the name of the class, the compiler is looking for a static class called Book OUTSIDE of the class you are in. Since you are calling them from inside the class itself, you do not need to do either as the compiler already knows where to look for these methods. When calling a class method from inside the same class, simply type the method name like so.

```
getDateOfPublication()
```